# Why are strange backslashes (escapes?) suddenly appearing in rendered code?

Tags: bug, code-formatting, code, stacks-editor

I've noticed that lately strange backslashes are appearing more and more frequently in edited code.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71763419/revisions) is another example. Is this a user failure or a bug in the site's code rendering?