# Why do we still have strange escape backslashes appearing in question code?

Tags: bug, code, stacks-editor

I was wondering why would users have that weird backslashes when pasting code. Now I noticed that this is a persisting issue<sup>[1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416802/punctuation-characters-being-escaped-in-code), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417243/why-are-strange-backslashes-escapes-suddenly-appearing-in-rendered-code), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419657/editor-automatically-adds-backslashes-to-escape-square-brackets-of-text-with-squ)</sup>. Why hasn't this been solved yet? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75771052/6574038). I've edited several similar posts in the last few days, and it's getting annoying.

Comment: Because it hasn't. The company is often slow at fixing stuff, but has so far proven exceptionally slow to fix severe problems with the Stacks editor in particular.

Comment: Because ctrl+k in the new editor makes an inline code rather than a block, even when you select an entire line or multiple lines of code. The new editor doesn't apply context when deciding which type of code block to make and instead has two separate buttons/keybinds, one of which previously was for the html/js snippit tool that also doesn't exist on the new editor.